# Passing model object as an argument with Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, flutter-getx

I need a model object on two screens.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is passing a model object (from one screen to another) required if we are using GetX?
2. If yes, how do we do it?

   ```
    return GestureDetector(
     onTap: () {
       Get.toNamed('/field_details/', arguments: fieldModel);
     },
   ```

In main.dart:

```
GetPage(
  name: '/field_details',
  page: () => FieldDetailsScreen(//how do I get the model to be passed here, it won't be available in the main function),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Get.arguments for that.

```
GetPage(
   name: '/field_details',
   page: () => FieldDetailsScreen(Get.arguments),
),
```

You will get your model here but you need to convert arguments into model by using your model's fromjosn method.